# dropdownlist inside a for loop asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

to build a dropdownlist inside for loop :

```
<%
for (int i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i++)
{
%>
   <ASP:Dropdownlist id="list" .... ></ASP:Dropdownlist

<%
}
%>
```

it would create three drop down list with the id = list
but how to get the value of the list from c# code behind

like :

```
 string x = list.SelectedValue;
```

The Question is : how to specify which one of those list I want to select it's value ?

P.S :
- I need to build it in asp.net not code behind because its a table and so complicated 
- without using a repeater

Comment: three dropdownlist with same id not a good thing :)

Comment: thats what am asking for